# Undefined variables: recommendedVersion and recommendedVersionEndOfSupport

Tags: administrator, joomla-3.6, error-reporting

I went into the "configuration.php", changed error reporting to "maximum", and now my Joomla admin page is suddenly blank white.

Then when I go to my backend login page, I get the following error messages:

> Notice: Undefined variable: recommendedVersion in
>   /home/mchardism/public_html/plugins/quickicon/phpversioncheck/phpversioncheck.php
>   on line 173
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: recommendedVersionEndOfSupport in
>   /home/mchardism/public_html/plugins/quickicon/phpversioncheck/phpversioncheck.php
>   on line 174
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on null in
>   /home/mchardism/public_html/plugins/quickicon/phpversioncheck/phpversioncheck.php
>   on line 174

So when I go to the phpversioncheck.php, lines 173 and 174, I see this:

[image]

And this is where I'm stuck. I don't know what I need to change in these lines to fix the issue. I've never opened this phpversioncheck.php file before and I'm not sure why it is suddenly giving me issues.

I am using:
Joomla 3.6.5

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Would you be able to provide the contents of the entire file?

Comment: You should not give too much attention to this error (this is just a PHP version check in this plugin), but you should update Joomla to the latest version and most probably this error will disappear. Joomla 3.6 is quite outdated. Why have you turned on maximum error reporting by the way?

Comment: I googled the white admin screen issue and saw a number of different posts suggest setting the error reporting to "maximum." I generally don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: @Lodder Which file are you referring to?

Comment: Ohh, I understand it now. There was already an error (with the white screen) and then you turned on maximum error reporting. Probably the server is using a newer PHP version and Joomla 3.6 does not support that PHP version. Maybe the PHP version has to be set back to PHP 5.6 and then a lot of updates, but it is better if you ask someone expert to help you with updating your Joomla site.

Comment: @Dave if my edit made your question less accurate, please edit your question to make the necessary repairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to fix it, open `/home/mchardism/public_html/plugins/quickicon/phpversioncheck/phpversioncheck.php`, find between the lines #108-132 the php version you use and change the date for `eos` (add few years, for example).

`eos` means `End of Support` and as @sharky said, this error `occurs on a combination of outdated PHP and Joomla! versions`. By changing `eos` date you simply allow to code continue to work without actual PHP/Joomla updating. For example I use Joomla 3.7.3 and PHP 5.6, but for today the latest versions are 3.9.14 and 7.4.1

This is more preferable way than accepted @omasan-esimaje 's answer, because in this case you still have the left vertical menu in admin panel. `mod_quickicon` is responsible for this menu, so disabling this plugin you disable this menu :)

Also in my case it was necessary to set `public $error_reporting` to `development` (ie `public $error_reporting = 'development'`) in `configuration.php`, instead of `maximum`, in order to see the error.

**In case, if you want to disable the plugin (according to @omasan-esimaje 's answer):**

The easiest way to open DB is to download [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) (Database management in a single PHP file) and put it next to `configuration.php` file, then open `yoursite.com/adminer-x.y-z.php` where `x.y-z` is the version of Adminer.

Necessary credentials for connection to DB you can find also in `configuration.php` and they look like:

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'juser';
public $password = 'jpass';
public $db = 'jdb';
```

For security reason remove Adminer once you disable the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

@Sharky gave a valid point that helped me solve the same problem. However, I would like to provide an alternative to help others who found it difficult to resolve this issue too. Rather than commenting out the line of code and breaking something else by accident,

> if you have access to the database via whatever means, you can disable
>   mod_quickicon by changing the enabled field bit from 1 to 0.

As in the image below;

[image: Sample record]

This record can be found in extensions table.

Note: Your extensions table may have a 'prefix'_extensions

Comment: Thank you for contributing. In the future, please avoid using the quoteblock formatting as a highlighter.  It is meant to be used to mark quoted text from some other source.  Often it is used to signify error messages but is also appropriately used to cite documentation.  If you wanted to quote a source, you could copy-paste the foreign text and include a link in your answer to the source.  For example: https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/disable-joomla-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Will do so next time @mickmackusa

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that occurs on a combination of outdated PHP and Joomla! versions. Measures have been taken to avoid this in the future and a fix will be available in 3.9.14.

It is recommended to keep PHP, Joomla!, its extensions and generally any software running on your server up-to-date. If you have no intention of doing that, your only other option is to disable `Quick Icon - PHP Version Check` plugin.

Comment: How would I disable this without being able to get into the Joomla backend? Is there some code I can insert somewhere in one of the .php files?

Comment: Normally the error should appear only after logging in and only on control panel. Other pages should be usable normally. But if you can't even login, comment out the line of code specified in the error message to make the error go away for now.

Answer (score 1):

On version 3.6 I solved the problem by changing the variable eos in the file
plugins/quickicon/phpversioncheck/phpversioncheck.php
from 2019 to 2025 on the lines 110 to 125.

Comment: The system has auto-flagged this answer as low-quality because of its length/content.  Thank you for joining the community and attempting to contribute.  Could you please expand on your answer to explicitly state the before and after code (in your answer) and explain (if you can) why this solution was good/appropriate.  Please remove the "Thank you" from your answer -- it isn't valuable.  Please take our [tour].